# Inserting data in my own singly linked list implementation

Tags: java, list

I have academic task to create a singly linked list implementation. The interface was provided. I tried to create it but I have issues with inserting any data into it. I tried to do that through the `prepend()` method that looks like this:

```
@Override
public void prepend(T data) {
    this.first = new Node<>(data, this.first);
}
```

and Node class looks like this:

```
private static class Node<T> {
    T value;
    Node<T> next;
    public Node(T value, Node<T> next) {
        this.value = value;
        this.next = next;
    }
}
```

The problem is that the program freezes at the moment of exiting the `prepend()` method. The strange thing thou is that it does not freeze on the assignment instruction cause I tried adding some console output before and after it and both were printed correctly. So:

```
@Override
public void prepend(T data) {
    System.out.println("sth1");
    this.first = new Node<>(data, this.first);
    System.out.println("sth2");
}
```

would show both messages, instanciate the Node properly and then freeze (looks like infinite loop). What am I doing wrong here?

--EDIT--

Execution code:

```
import com.sda.structures.list.List;
import com.sda.structures.list.SinglyLinkedList;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> list = new SinglyLinkedList<>();
        list.prepend(1);
    }
}
```

The List in this code is the interface provided not the standard java Collection. It can't freeze after exiting the method cause there is nothing else there... Debugger stops on the last curly brace of `prepend()` and shows "collecting data" on every parameter. The rest of the code is never run in this test scenario so it would not be useful in this case.

--EDIT 2--

It was an issue with a JVM. After restarting JVM everything works correctly.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your full source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Comment: You could also include the code where prepend() is executed

Comment: How you know that it "freezes at the moment of exiting the `prepend()` method" and not after returning from it? or even later?

Comment: Prepend is correct. Time for debugging.